# Swift UIGestureRecognizer not working when added in initWithCoder

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom `UIView` subclass with UI designed in xib.

```
class MyView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadView()
        commonInit()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadView()
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        let rightSwipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipe"))
        rightSwipeRecognizer.direction = .Right
        dayInfoView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipeRecognizer)
    }

    func swipe() {
        println("swiped")
    }    

    private func loadView() {
        let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        let views = mainBundle.loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: self, options: nil)
        let view = views.first as? UIView
        addSubview(view!)
    }
}
```

In my storyboard, I've added a view to VC and ensured that user interaction is enabled on that view. The result: **no swipe handling**

In case I add my view manually everything **works fine**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myView = MyViewframe: CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 200))
    view.addSubview(myView)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're adding the gesture recognizer to `dayInfoView`, but where is that variable declared?

Comment: @ndmeiri yes, I've checked it with po in lldb

Comment: No, I'm asking you to show the code where `dayInfoView` is declared.

Comment: Also, did you set a breakpoint at the `addGestureRecognizer(:)` call to make sure execution reaches that point?

Comment: @ndmeiri yes, sure:)